# Health Kit SDK issue

Tags: ios8, xcode6

Getting error while running apple sample code  [Fit: Store and Retrieve HealthKit Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Fit/Introduction/Intro.html).

> Error Domain=com.apple.healthkit Code=4 "Missing com.apple.developer.healthkit entitlement.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things to check:

1. Does your provisioning profile includes support for HealthKit?
2. Does your bundle identifier use the same ID referenced in the provisioning profile with support for HealthKit?

Answer (score 1):

or Activate Health kit in Capabilities

[image]